# How would I create this MySQL Schema?

Tags: mysql, database, schema

Suppose I have a blog post entity.

- It has many attributes
- It has comments attached to it.
- It has many states (deleted/locked/invisible, etc).
- It has many "tags". (keywords, school_id, user_id)

Obviously, comments should be its own table, with a many-to-one relationship to Blog table.

**But what about "states" or "tags"? Would you put that in another table?  Or would you stick that in many columns?**

**What about attributes...if they get too big? Because as my website grows, the blog post will have more and more attributes attached (title, author, blah, blah....).  What happens if the attribute list goes as high as 100?**

Comment: always in another table. if you embed them in a single field, you negate the purpose of having a relational database - you lose the ability to relate things.

Comment: "states" would be its own table?

Comment: State should be just a column in posts table. Keywords should definitely be in a separate table, related by post id, with primary key on both keyword and post id columns. Don't see why attributes list will grow. If you're about to maintain any kind of structure, attribute list should be the same, so it makes sense to have attributes as columns in posts table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, states should be a tightly structured thing, so you should create separate columns for them. Think about what you need at the beginning, but you can easily add one or two more columns later.

Tags like keywords shouldn't be stored in columns, because the amount is growing rapidly over time. That wouldn't make any sense. So for that, build a table with id and keyword in it and a link table with post_id and keyword_id. You could also omit the keyword_id and directly link post_id and keyword.
Make sure that both columns combined define the primary key, so you can not end up with a keyword stored several time to one particular post.

For attributes it can be the same. It is not a bad practice to create an attribute table with attribute_id, attribute_name and maybe more information and a link table attribute_id and post_id and content.
You can also easily enhance it to be multilingual by using attribute_ids.

Comments are the same, stored in a separate table with a link to a user and a post: comment_id, user_id, post_id, content and maybe parent_id, which can be a comment_id if you want comments to be commentable again.

That's it for a brief overview.

Comment: Thanks! But why can't "states" be its own table? And then I would have a one-to-one relationship with Post.  Because I imagine having 10-20 states...

Comment: Ok, it's no problem to have a separate table for states. I was not aware of the amount of states you have. However, you should always have an eye on your tables and joins. Getting all data for one post means to retrieve a lot of information from different tables.

Comment: So, I know you posted the question with the mysql tag, and therefore the following is not relevant for you at all, but maybe it's worth to think about a different database at all. If you are about to store not only posts but different types of data (pages, articles, whatever), have a changing set off attributes and maybe states, a NoSQL DB (e.g. CouchDB) can be an alternative. I for myself am currently examining exactly that.

Comment: Thanks. Is it bad to "retrieve a lot of information from different tables?"

Comment: It's not bad at all, but it takes obviously more time than retrieving data from just a small set of tables. If you're going to show one element (a post in this case) in detail, you won't see it, but if you want to _list_ your posts and need information from a lot of joined tables and you have to retrieve them all for say 25 posts, it can be time consuming. It's good practice to set up your database as desired and fill it with a huge amount of test data. Then run the queries you need for your application and measure them (via explain and actual time).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample:

Again.. It's just a sample.. There are other approaches that you can use.

Here we go:

```
-- basic-basic blog
CREATE TABLE blog_entry (
    blog_entry_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    blog_entry_title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    blog_entry_text VARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL,
    create_date DATETIME,
    state_id INT
);

-- create a look-up table for your blog entry's state
CREATE TABLE be_state (
     state_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (state_id)
);

-- create a look-up table for your blog entry's tag/s
CREATE TABLE be_tag (
     tag_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (tag_id)
);

-- a table to store multiple tags to one entry
CREATE TABLE blog_entry_tags (
    blog_entry_id INT NOT NULL,
    tag_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (blog_entry_id, tag_id)
);

-- a table to store definitions of attributes
CREATE TABLE be_attribute (
    attribute_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name CHAR(30)
);

-- now have a table to which you can assign multiple attributes to one blog
-- of course, this is if I understand you correctly
-- where you want to have additional attributes
-- aside from the basic properties of a blog entry 
-- and will allow you, if you choose to do it
-- to not necessarily have all attributes for each entry
CREATE TABLE blog_entry_attributes (
    blog_entry_id INT NOT NULL,
    attribute_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (blog_entry_id, attribute_id) 
    -- PK enforces one blog entry may have only one attribute of its type
    -- meaning, no multiple attributes of 'location' attribute,
    -- for example, for one blog. Unless of course you wrote half the entry
    -- in one location and finished it in the next.. then you should
    -- NOT enforce this primary key
);
```

1. `blog_entry` - your main table, where the goods go
2. `be_state` - define them here, and insert their `state_id` values in `blog_entry.state_id`
3. `be_tag` - have multiple tags like we do here
4. `blog_entry_tags` - since you can possibly have many tags for one blog entry, store them here and insert `blog_entry.blog_entry_id` and the corresponding `be_tag.tag_id` together. one tag of its type per blog entry. meaning you can't tag entry#1 (for example) the tag `php` twice or more.
5. `be_attribute` - store attribute definitions here like location, author, etc
6. `blog_entry_attributes` - similar to `blog_entry_tags` where you can assign one or more than one `be_attribute` to a blog entry.

Again, this is just one approach.

Comment: I know it's a lengthy post, but I hope that it will somehow help give you ideas on how to go about it.. This is just an example I cooked up right now, so it won't be the best.